# Tableau Stacking latitude and longitude from different source

Tags: tableau-desktop

I wanted to stack two geographical visualization into one.

1. Chleropeth map
2. Latitude and Longitude information

Note that both data for Cheropeth map and Latitude and Longtitude information are from different source/file.

**Problem**
This is my current situation, where Top is the cheropeth map, and bottom is suppose to be the latitude and Longitude information, where i followed the tutorial from.

The bottom information is not showing up.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_dualaxis.htm

[image]

This is how I input the second lat long information into the bottom axis.

[image]

This is the second map where I have created in a separate sheet but my intend is to combine both into one.

[image]

Comment: Try writing a calculated field in your recommender data source that calls the Make_Point function to turn your lat, long fields into a spatial field. Then when you put that field on one of the marks cards, that will populate the generated last/long fields

Comment: There is more to it than that, but that way you won’t be mixing your lat, long field with the generated ones. Might make it easier to manage the dual axis setup, always using the generated fields